# Square roots of -25i?

Tags: trigonometry

How exactly would I find these? I know you have to plug it into the nth root of a complex number formula, but when I try to find the argument for the trig form, i just get undefined.

Comment: $x^2=-25 i\iff (x/5)^2=-i.$  Find real $A,B$ with $-i=(A+i B)^2=A^2-B^2+2 A B i.$

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to calculate a square root:

**Option 1**
$$x+iy=\sqrt{-25i}$$
$$(x+iy)^2=-25i$$
$$x^2+2xy-y^2=-25i$$
$$x^2-y^2=0\text{ and }2xy=-25$$
$$x=\pm y$$
We select the negative root as the positive root will lead to no solution ($y^2=-25$)
$$-2y^2-25$$
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{25}{2}}$$
$$y=\frac{5}{\sqrt2}$$
So $$\sqrt{-25i}=\pm\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt2}-\frac{5}{\sqrt2}i\right)$$

**Option 2**
$$z=\sqrt{-25i}$$
$$z^2=-25i$$
$$z^2=25e^{i\left(\frac{-\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)}\text{ where }n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$z=5e^{i\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi n\right)}$$
$$z=5e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}\text{ or }5e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}}$$
$$\sqrt{-25i}=\pm\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt2}-\frac{5}{\sqrt2}i\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

For a number in the complex plane and not in the positive reals, one easy way to find its square roots is to figure out its argument.  In this case, the argument is $3\pi/2$ because $-25i$ is on the negative imaginary line, so you have to rotate a number on the positive real line by $3\pi/2$ radians counterclockwise around the origin to get to $-25i$ (i.e., by three-quarters of a turn).  One square root of $-25i$ thus has argument $3\pi/4$, i.e., half the argument of $-25i$.  It needs to have norm $5$, since $\sqrt{25}=5$.  The number $(-5+5i)/\sqrt{2}$ fits the bill, having the desired argument and norm, and indeed its square is $-25i$.  (The other square root is minus that.)

Alternatively as suggested by a commenter you can write $(A+Bi)^2=-25i$ where $A$ and $B$ are unknowns to be determined, do the squaring, identify  real and imaginary parts of both sides, and determine $A$ and $B$.

Comment: So why does one of the roots have an argument that is half the argument of -25i?

Comment: In general, the argument of the product of two complex numbers is the sum of the arguments, provided the latter sum is within $[0,2\pi)$.  Thus if $a$ has half the argument of $b$, we have that $a^2$ has the same argument as $b$.  To me this geometric way of thinking is helpful but it may not be helpful to all.